# Insert a node at any position in Linked List implementation in Java

Tags: java

I have written this code to insert a new node at any position of the "Linked List"

I know there is build-in library in Java; I am writing this as a practice for Java.

But I get error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I don't know where the problem. Here is my code:

```
 public void insertAtPos(int val , int pos) {

        Node nptr = new Node(val, null);                
        Node current = start;

        /*  Crawl to the requested index */
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
            current = current.getLink();
        }

        /*  Set the new node's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference  */
        nptr.setLink(current.getLink());

        /*  Set the new node's next-node reference to the new node  */
        current.setLink(nptr);

        size++ ;
  }     

/*  Function to set link to next Node  */
public void setLink(Node n) {
    link = n;
} 

/*  Function to get link to next node  */
public Node getLink() {
    return link;
}
```

Comment: What value are you using for `pos`, and how many items are in the list?

Comment: I have tried "pos" for 0, 1, and 2. My list has 3 nodes at first. Its should be working for any list with any number at any position.

Comment: @Hengameh At which line you're getting the nullpointer exception

Comment: @AndersonVieira, I have already read that question. It couldn't help me.

Comment: when I set pos=2, this error happens. for pos=0 and pos=1, nothing happens.

Comment: in the middle your code is ok, @Hengameh, but please *check the bounds* ! (what happens on `pos==0`, what on `pos==size` ?..or even beyond^^)

Comment: @Hengameh It would help to see the error stack trace.

Comment: The cause could be with variable "start". Where did you initialize it?

Comment: Thank you, I will check pos==0, pos==size and start as well. does anybody know what "nptr" and "ptr" stands for?

Comment: Your code will throw an NPE if `start` is `null`, or if `pos` is greater than or equal to the length of the list (supposing the last element's link is `null`).  If neither of those is the case, but the code presented nevertheless throws an NPE, then your links are somehow buggered.

Comment: "does anybody know what "nptr" and "ptr" stands for?"  There is no `ptr` in your code.  There is an `nptr`, and its meaning seems clear, but if this is *your* code then how can you not know what it represents?

Comment: This is the code I have written, but I see in other codes, which I am trying to get help from them, they use "nptr" for their first node, and then "ptr" for the second one. I am just wondering if they have special meaning. I searched on net as well, but I couldn't find any reasonable answer for that.

Comment: @AndersonVieira, "error stack trace", could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: error stack trace - call stack from the start of the java thread to the point of error. When an error occur you will see this printing in your logs. What do you see other than java.lang.NullPointerException contains the error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an IDE (I suggest you do) e.g. Eclipse, put a line break at the start of your method. If you don't know how, you can see this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_line_breakpoints.htm). Then try running your application in Debug Mode. By this you can go through each of your variable and inspect if it contains null value.

This link will give you better understanding: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure `pos` is no greater `size`. Second your insert algorithm seems wrong. To crawl to the requested index, it should be `for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++){` and you must handle `pos == 0` to change the start node.

Comment: Agreed.  This does not actually answer the question, however, which is about the reason for the NPE.